# Unable to delete a user with lots of content?

Tags: 7, users

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
 HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=462&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/evangfep/public_html/manas/includes/module.inc on line 895
```

While deleting user , I get the above error.
How can I fix the above issue, since its server is shared hosting , I am unable to increase the maximum execution time.

Comment: The above URI states that you are using a batch request already. May I ask how you are deleting the users?

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I am using default drupal way to delete the user from admin/people section . This is what even surprised me as well as batch request is said to prevent timeout but this does not seem to occur here